# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init'), ReactJS, gapi error

Tags: reactjs, google-signin, react-google-login

I am using react-google-login to sign in to my react app with gapi-script and gapi.
The versions are:
"gapi": "^0.0.3",
"gapi-script": "^1.2.0",
"react-google-login": "^5.2.2",

The google login button is not rendering when I open the page, and I get the error

```
login.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')
    at login.js:65:4
    at gapiScript.js:32:267
    at tb (gapiScript.js:24:468)
    at t (gapiScript.js:32:250)
    at m.<computed> (gapiScript.js:32:353)
    at F.<computed> [as loaded_0] (gapiScript.js:32:417)
    at cb=gapi.loaded_0:1:6
(anonymous) @ login.js:65
(anonymous) @ gapiScript.js:32
tb @ gapiScript.js:24
t @ gapiScript.js:32
m.<computed> @ gapiScript.js:32
F.<computed> @ gapiScript.js:32
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:1


gapiScript.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: _.pk is not a function
    at cb=gapi.loaded_1:14:483
    at gapiScript.js:30:52
    at Yb (gapiScript.js:33:116)
    at Zb (gapiScript.js:29:489)
    at p (gapiScript.js:32:9)
    at t (gapiScript.js:32:242)
    at m.<computed> (gapiScript.js:32:353)
    at F.<computed> [as loaded_1] (gapiScript.js:32:417)
    at cb=gapi.loaded_1:1:6
```

My code for google auth is

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const initClient = () => {
            gapi.client.init({
                clientId: clientId,
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
            });
        };
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
    },[]);
.
.
.
.
return(
.
.
<GoogleLogin        
clientId='clientId'
buttonText='Login/Signup with Google'           
scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
onSuccess={handleLogin}
onFailure={handleFailure}>
</GoogleLogin>
.
.)
```

Can someone help me figure out what the issue is?

I tried setting timeout to the gapi.load function, but this didn't work. I can't see a way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

there is an update to the usage of gapi script,

can you please follow the steps provided here

https://github.com/LucasAndrad/gapi-script-live-example/blob/master/src/components/GoogleLogin.js

it should work, if you follow the steps

and for your reference, here is new useEffect code,

```
useEffect(() => {
    const setAuth2 = async () => {
      const auth2 = await loadAuth2(gapi, GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, 'email');
      if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
        updateUser(auth2.currentUser.get());
      } else {
        attachSignin(document.getElementById('gButton'), auth2);
      }
    };
    setAuth2();
  }, []);


const attachSignin = (element, auth2) => {
    auth2.attachClickHandler(
      element,
      {},
      (googleUser) => {
        updateUser(googleUser);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    );
  };
  const updateUser = (currentUser) => {
    const name = currentUser.getBasicProfile().getName();
    const profileImg = currentUser.getBasicProfile().getImageUrl();
  };
```